# AclClassIdUtils : Unable to obtain the class id type

Tags: java, spring-security, acl

I have integrated configuration code for ACL on a permission level for my entities. Everything works fine and it even checks if a user holds a particular permission and denies/allows access based on their roles. But whenever a permission is checked I get the following error in the console which I would like to eliminate.

I already tried to add the column class_id_type to the acl_class but that did not change anything.

```
@Column(name = "class_id_type")
@Null
private String classIdType;
```

I am using 
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-core', version: '5.1.2.RELEASE'

2019-05-21 13:42:17.593 DEBUG 4036 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.acls.jdbc.AclClassIdUtils   : Unable to obtain the class id type

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name class_id_type was not found in this ResultSet.

Comment: Maybe the column does not exist in the DB?

Comment: No, it does unfortunately :/

Comment: It's [this bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7598)

Answer (score 1):

`class_id_type` is selected from `acl_class` in default **BasicLookupStrategy**, but `class_id_type` column has been changed to class in spring security official site

```
create table acl_class(
    id bigint generated by default as identity(start with 100) not null primary key,
    class varchar_ignorecase(100) not null,
    constraint unique_uk_2 unique(class)
);
```

So, just create yourself: public class MyLookupStrategy implementing LookupStrategy from BasicLookupStrategy, and public class MyAclClassIdUtils from AclClassIdUtils

then change 'class_id_type' to 'class',
it should works then.